# When i post image to instagram from my app it directly opens to filter section of Instagram but i want it to open cropping section of Instagram?

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

```
- (IBAction)postToInstagram:(id)sender {
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
    NSString *jpgPath=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Home_1_instgram.igo"];
    UIImage *imageN = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", jpgPath]];

    //        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageDetail.image) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@",jpgPath]];
    self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";

    self.documentController = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
    NSString *caption = self.catalogueImage.caption; //settext as Default Caption

    //Removing pre-filled captions from mobile sharing
    //http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing

    self.documentController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Here Give what you want to share" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];

    NSLog(@"caption: %@",caption);

    [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect inView: self.view animated: YES ];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"INSTAGRAM NOT FOUND" message:@"Please install instagram to post to instagram." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to it. In iOS Instagram directly sends user to the filter section whereas in android the user is directed to the crop section. It was mentioned in Instagram iPhone Hook.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

i have changed something in your code :

you should use  `com.instagram.photo`

```
- (IBAction)postToInstagram:(id)sender {

if ([self schemeAvailable:@"instagram://app"])
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
    NSString *jpgPath=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Home_1_instgram.igo"];
    UIImage *imageN = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1304.PNG"];

    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageN) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@",jpgPath]];
    self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";

    self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
    NSString *caption = @"YourCaption"; //settext as Default Caption

    //Removing pre-filled captions from mobile sharing
    //http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing

    self.documentController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Here Give what you want to share" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];

    NSLog(@"caption: %@",caption);

    [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect inView: self.view animated: YES ];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"INSTAGRAM NOT FOUND" message:@"Please install instagram to post to instagram." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
    [alert show];
  }
}
```

Comment: i am still getting the same problem Mohamad Frahand i am still getting to the filter section of instagram instead of cropping section

Comment: but i had try your action in my code  and after that send it here !
can you upload your code ?

Comment: i am using NSURL instead of schemeAvailable and everything else is same    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
    {

Comment: i  have only add :
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>instagram</string>
    </array>

and call this action my bro.
if you want you can push your sample to try to fix it.

Comment: <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
   <string>com.instagram.exclusivegram</string>
   <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <array>
    <string>com.instagram.exclusivegram</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array>
 <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
 <string>1</string>
 <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
 <string></string>
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>instagram</string>
 </array>


when i change string to com.instagram.exclusivegram to photo it just taking me to the filter section of instagram instead of cropping section in Instagram

Comment: i know the difference between com.instagram.exclusigram & com.instagram.photo i just want my app to send it to the cropping section of instagram where we can crop the image but its directly taking me to the filter section